# QT Custom Layout Example For Overlappig Widgets Doesn't Compile

Tags: c++, qt

Using QT 5.11, I am attempting to overlap a series of widgets.  Using Google, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968622/making-widgets-partly-overlap-in-a-qt-layout), which references [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).  I've copied the source code, but it doesn't compile.  The problem is that the header file attempts to initialize QLayout with 3 different signatures, none of which exist.

```
CardLayout(QWidget *parent, int dist): QLayout(parent, 0, dist) {}
CardLayout(QLayout *parent, int dist): QLayout(parent, dist) {}
CardLayout(int dist): QLayout(dist) {}
```

None of these signatures appear in either the 4.8 or 5.12 documentation for QLayout, and I have been unable to find any reference to this usage.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The card example comes from Qt3 (Stone Age). QLayout used to have the following interface in Qt3:

```
QLayout ( QWidget * parent, int margin = 0, int spacing = -1, const char * name = 0 );
QLayout ( QLayout * parentLayout, int spacing = -1, const char * name = 0 );
QLayout ( int spacing = -1, const char * name = 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was confused because the web address of the page (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) specifically mentions qt5  That page could use some updating.  Do you know how to report that to the maintainers?  (A bug report doesn't seem appropriate to me.)